# Send email when someone tries to open VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to restrict access to the VBA code in an Excel file.

I tried doing this by `Share & Protect Workbook`, but the file does not allow the macros to run and it shows an error.

So now I want to send an email if someone tries to open the VBA code by hacking it. I want the VBA code to do this. Is that possible?

Any reply is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can lock the VBA project by opening the IDE Window and right-clicking on the project name and select the <kbd>Properties...</kbd>.

[image]

Then click the <kbd>Protection</kbd> tab and check the <kbd>Lock project for viewing</kbd> checkbox and enter a password.

[image]

Comment: Thank You aduguid.....:)  But even if the same is protected using locking it, there are also vba code to hack it..... So can it be possible to over come that too.  Or finally, I have to end up taking that risk of codes being accessed by people via hack...

Comment: Or else is there any such way that if anyone tries to open vba window the system or a kind to vba code sends a mail to me about his mail which i would take as soon as the excel file is opened...

Comment: If you're worried about the security of the VBA project, you can migrate it to VB.NET.